# Kotlin - Can One Button Apply 2 Action?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a Button that can apply 2 action. For example, when i press the button-- it makes the ImageView VISIBLE, and when i press it again-- the ImageView goes INVISIBLE, just like **switch**. Is it really possible?

```
val btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
btn1.setOnClickListener {
    labu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: You can make the button do whatever you want... For example, check if it's first visible, or not, then change to the appropriate value

Comment: Yeah, I understand theoretically. But since i just started learning kotlin 3 days ago, i cant implement it in code, that's why I asking

Comment: this can be done with simple `if(condition) { .. } else { ... }` logic

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin it's just 1 line of code to toggle the visibility of a `View`:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener {
    labu.visibility = if (labu.visibility  == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: Same in Java. `labu.setVisibility(labu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: @Zoe I was pointing out that this is very easy in Kotlin. If I had to write this in Java I would also maybe have to explain the ternary operator.